# Multiple Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good morning experts.

I really need some help on a report that I am trying to create. So far I have it, but the only way I can get it to work is to create 2 separate reports and then merge them in Excel. And even then it takes a lot or work and time for Excel to prepare the calculations.
The report is a pipeline report for our suppliers but for specific manufacturers. I am using 2 queries from 2 different servers.

- **Query 1**. All products on "Opportunities". I will list the part number, cost and sell.
- **Query 2**. All products from Supplier databases. I only pull the manufacturers that I care about. It will list the part number, manufacturer name and list. I also have to modify the Manufacturer name to be consistent. For example CISCO can be "Cisco Software", "Cisco Hardware", "Cisco License", I need this to be just CISCO. I take care of this with a CASE statement. I want to report base on list price. This query can have up to 200K lines.

In Excel I bring both queries and do a vlookup to match the part number and bring the Manufacturer and List Price. Then I can pivot.

I am using tSQL to build my query.

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple outer join.  what have you tried so far in T-SQL? Do you have a linked server from one db to the other?

Answer (score 2):

To do this in one query, you would need to setup a Linked Server.  I would check with a DBA at your company to see if this is something they are willing to setup or if you have admin access to these servers you can set it up yourself ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) is information on setting up a linked server for SQL Server 2008.  Once that is done you would use 4 part naming to reference the different servers, databases and table, and JOIN on part number and then work the rest of your magic.

The key is getting the Linked Server setup so you can reference the supplier database from the other one in a single query. Another option would be to use SQL Server Integration Services to JOIN your 2 data sets.

It would help if you posted your 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we could do with some clarification on the details here, however with some simple assumptions I believe that you are looking for something like the below to generate the matched data set,

This solution assumes you have a set of linked servers,

```
SELECT Q1.PartNumber, Q1.Cost, Q1.Sell, Q2.PartNumber, Q2.ManufacturerName, Q2.List
FROM ( SQL to generate results for Query 1) AS Q1
INNER JOIN ( SQL to generate results for Query 2) AS Q2
ON Q1.PartNumber = Q2.PartNumber
```

This would effective return both data sets and join them together would get you to the point where you can run your pivot in excel.